# Android:: Highlight a non-selected button

Tags: android

I am working on a game project.

I have 4 buttons on my screen. User has to select one of the 4. If user selects the correct one, it works fine. but if user selects incorrect one, I want to highlight the correct answer even though user didnt clicked it.

I have presentation due tomorrow. Can anybody point me to some example source or explain it here, as to how can I accomplish it.

Comment: why don't you change the background of that button. You can use `setBackgroundColor(int color)` or `setBackgroundResource(int resid)`

Comment: Okay....I will try that but I am not sure what happens if I change the background of the image..as I haven't used it before. I will try this.

Comment: why not show a toast than changing colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever user clicks on the incorrect button simply call :

```
correctButton.setPressed(true)
```

This will highlight the correct button as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the correct buttons background color or image while clicking other buttons

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing..

1. Call `Button.requestFocus()` method to get the focus.
2. Create a custom selector for you Button's background. there

   `< item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/your_color" />`